# Cluster-Robust Standard Errors for clogit in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, glm, standard-error

At the moment I have a binary conditional-Logit model, that looks like this:

`model<- clogit(y ~ independent variable+ control variables + factor(year) + factor(region) + strata(id), data=xy)`,

where Years, Regions and the ID have fixed effects.

My Problem is, that I don't know how to get cluster corrected standard errors with clogit. Is it possible to get the corrected se with the following formula?

`modelCC<-  clogit(y ~ independent variable+ control variables + factor(syear) + factor(region) + strata(id), data=xy, robust =TRUE, method = "efron" )`

Are these measures sufficient to gain cluster corrected standard errors for clogit in R? Should I take another way? And how important are cluster corrected standard errors for the analysis of my model?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Best regards,

Philipp

Comment: Try `?survival::cluster`.

Comment: First, thank you for the fast answer. To use the cluster method, I need to use another method than "exact" like "efron". Would that change my method fundamentally or are the results pretty similar?  Best regards

Comment: Good question, probably better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) though. I suggest to open there a new question.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?